# What files get executed when login using ssh?

Tags: bash, debian

i have 3 machines that using Debian 6.0.7 for PPC

when i logged in using SSH, one of it's $PATH variables is somehow different than other two

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

i wonder, which files got executed on that machine when i'm using SSH? i already checked .bashrc, but nothing there that similar to

```
PATH=/bla/bla:$PATH
```

Comment: Check /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc, it's probably in one of those.

Comment: ah thank you so much :3 it's on /etc/profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc/profile is called on login, whether normal or via ssh.

/etc/bash.bashrc contains global bash settings and is called when bash is executed as well as your individual .bashrc